# What is Jarasandha's military force according to BORI's Harivamsa?

Tags: war, harivamsa, kings, jarasandha

According to [this](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_034.html) chapter of that version of Harivamsa, the military force of Jarasandha in his attacks on Mathura consisted of the kingdoms of Hastinapura, Videha (capital of Mithila), Bahlika, Chedi, Karusha, Pragjyotisha, Vidharbha, Paundraka, Vanga, Kalinga, Yavana, Suparshva, Dasharna, Kashi, Madra, Trigarta, Soubha, Darada, Pandya, Sindhu, Gandhara and Kashmir. And [this](http://mahabharata-resources.org/harivamsa/vishnuparva/hv_2_035.html) chapter describes that in total there are 20 akshouhinis consisting of the army of Jarasandha and was also supported by Panchala, Bhoja, Shini, Malava, Avanti, Matsya, Kekaya and Nishada.

But, was that information of the military force retained according to BORI's Harivamsa?